# Configure baseurl in Magento 2 env.php or config.php?

Tags: magento2, configuration, base-url

Is it possible to configure the base-url (secure & unsecure) within the array-based configuration files like `env.php` or `config.php`?

I tried with `env.php` but it didn't give me much:

```
<?php
return array (
    'web' => [
        'unsecure' => ['base_url' => 'test'],
        'secure' => ['base_url' => 'test'],
    ],
    ...
```

But it might just be that I'm overlooking something.

It however works nicely when I use the core config table, e.g. setting it with magerun2:

```
$ n98-magerun2.phar config:set web/secure/base_url https://example.com
web/secure/base_url => https://example.com
$ n98-magerun2.phar config:set web/unsecure/base_url http://example.com
web/unsecure/base_url => http://example.com
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can do that from Magento 2.2 in following way. Put this code in *env.php* file

```
<?php
return [
    'system' => [
        'default' => [
            'system' => [
                'smtp' => [
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => '25'
                ]
            ],
            'web' => [
                'unsecure' => [
                    'base_url' => 'http://test/',
                    'base_link_url' => '{{unsecure_base_url}}'
                ],
                'secure' => [
                    'base_url' => 'https://test/',
                    'base_link_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}'
                ],
                'default' => [
                    'front' => 'cms'
                ],
                'cookie' => [
                    'cookie_domain' => 'test'
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ],

    ...
```

This is for default scope solution, but you can define scope in same way as discrabed on
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/prod/config-reference-var-name.html
section *Find a website or store view scope in the database*

Comment: Confirmed this in 2.2.5.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, since in Magento you can config multiple stores, and since these are store specific configs, you cannot store them in `env.php`. `config.php` is only for module related info.

It is also the reason there are 2 commands :

```
bin/magento setup:store-config:set
```

for store related config, which is stored in the database, and

```
bin/magento setup:config:set
```

which sets environment configs in `env.php`

Comment: Is there no way to add store-specific settings files, containing the base-url for a specific store?

Comment: No @Andrea it can only be store in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

One way to set configuration per store, is to set environment variables: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/prod/config-reference-var-name.html

I have tried and could not get them working so far. The variables I set showed up when I put `phpinfo();die();` at the top of `index.php`, so I'm not sure why they were not used.